# What does "an orderly man" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> an orderly man

What's the meaning of "an orderly man"?

'orderly' means 'tidy'. Does "an orderly man" have a specific usage or can it be used broadly?

Comment: Context, context, context!

Comment: Its only "specific usage" would be to name or relate to the book of the same name. Since a summary description of that book, as well as the definitions of "orderly" are readily available by basic research, this question requires more detail to qualify as on-topic for this community. If, after further research, you still have a question, you might provide more information about what you know and why you ask: for example, if you are thinking to use it in a particular context for a particular purpose.

Answer (score 1):

*An orderly* is used to refer to a hospital attendant who is responsible for the non-medical care of patients and the maintenance of order and cleanliness.

Also, it can also mean a soldier who carries out orders or performs minor tasks for a superior officer. *An orderly sergeant* is another term for him.

[Here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/orderly) is the Merriam-Webster Dictionary reference.

*An orderly man*, however, should simply mean a neat, methodical, well-organized, or well-behaved man.